# Not showing question action on main page

Tags: bug

I've noticed this:

[image]
*Showed only 26 mins ago (Without modified, answered or asked).*

Comment: Im not sure I follow. Can you state the problem (I may just be being thick)

Comment: @Jamiec, do you see it now? Not really a problem, just a small tiny bug.

Comment: No, no I dont. Looks like that question was last touched (written/edited/etc) 26 minutes previously. What am I missing? (Im almost certain that this is obvious, and im being thick)

Comment: Oooh you mean it doesnt say "modified" or "asked" or "edited" (I missed that last line in your question. reading comprehension FTW)

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this has to do with the question having been migrated from health.se, there really was no activity here at skeptics on that question at the time that you viewed the question page.

Comment: Reported on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267234/very-minor-bug-when-migrating-questions

Comment: Good point. Thanks for reporting.